# Java Output Errors Within While Loop?

Tags: java

```
package javahistogramtwo;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class JavaHistogramTwo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
           int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int mark = 0;
        int largest = 0, smallest = 0;
        int rangeOne = 0, rangeTwo = 0, rangeThree = 0, rangeFour = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter marks, -1 to finish: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (in.hasNextInt()) {
            {

                while (mark != -1) {
                    mark = in.nextInt();

                    if (mark < -1 || mark > 100) {
                        System.out.println("Error: Enter Valid Input Type: "
                                + "Numbers from 0 - 100 for Marks. Or -1 to finish.");
                    } else if (mark != -1) {
                        sum = sum + mark;
                        count++;

                        if (count == 1) {
                            largest = mark;
                            smallest = mark;
                        } else {
                            if (mark > largest) {
                                largest = mark;
                            }
                            if (mark < smallest) {
                                smallest = mark;
                            }

                            if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 29) {
                                rangeOne++;
                            } else if (mark >= 30 && mark <= 39) {
                                rangeTwo++;
                            } else if (mark >= 40 && mark <= 69) {
                                rangeThree++;
                            } else if (mark >= 70 && mark <= 100) {
                                rangeFour++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error 1");
        }

        System.out.print("0-29: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < rangeOne; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("30-39: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < rangeTwo; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("40-69: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < rangeThree; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("70-100: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < rangeFour; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println("");
        if (count > 0) {
            System.out.println("Largest mark is: " + largest);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No data");
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            System.out.println("Smallest mark is: " + smallest);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No data");
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            double average = sum / count;
            System.out.println("Average marks: " + average);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No data");
        }

        if (count > 0) {
            System.out.println(rangeOne + rangeTwo + rangeThree + rangeFour + 
                    " Total Number of Students");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No data");
        }

        {
            System.out.println(rangeThree + rangeFour + " Number of Student Passed"
                    + " - (40 Marks or Above)");
        }
    }
}
```

Hello.

Above is my code for an assignment.

I am trying to display the amount of inputted numbers in a star format.
Such as:

- 0 - 29: **
- 30 - 39: *
- 40 - 69: **
- 70 - 100: ***

In this case, the stars represent the amount of user inputted numbers (8). Two ranging from 0 - 29. One ranging from 30 - 39. Two ranging from 40 - 69. And three ranging from 70 - 100.

I then display the largest, lowest and average marks. This part is working.

I then print out the number of students entered. (8 in this case).

And then using if mark is greater than or equal to 40 as a condition, display pass students. (5 in this case).

I have all the display correct.

However, with the stars, number of students and pass students. This displays wrong. It always shows as one less than what has been entered. So in this case 7 (should be 8) stars would be printed off. 7 (should be 8) students would display as entered. And 4 (should be 5) students will display as passed.

I have gone over my code. Made some changes in a second NetBeans application. But am still having the same problem and don't see where my problem lies.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks. :)

For a more clear example:

---

- User input:
- 15
- 20
- 20
- 50
- 60
- 70
- 70
- 85
- 99
- 100
- 100
- (-1 to finish)

---

- Expected output:
- 0 - 29: ***
- 30 - 39:
- 40 - 69: **
- 70 - 100: ******
- Largest mark is: 100
- Smallest mark is :15
- Average marks:62.0
- 11 Students Entered
- 8 Number of Students Passed - (40 Marks or Above)

---

- Actual output:
- 0-29: **                //One missing star here
- 30-39:
- 40-69: **
- 70-100: ******
- Largest mark is: 100
- Smallest mark is: 15
- Average marks: 62.0
- 10 Total Number of Students    //Calculation wrong, should be 11
- 7 Number of Student Passed - (40 Marks or Above)   // Calculation
  wrong, should be 8

Comment: could you include a sample input, sample ouput and expected output. it would make it more clear what you´re trying to achive

Comment: It is because in your else condition to this `if(count == 1)` you are calculating the further things. Instead complete the else block first and then make `rangeone++` calculations.

Comment: Isn't there already an answer for this question you asked yesterday ?

Comment: Did you try changing the scope of your else part? It is not producing the expected output because currently you aren't handling the scope properly.

Comment: @Squeegee Did my answer helped you ? Can you give a feedback ? Is it working or not yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Your first missing input as many already told you is due to the first grade being ignored and not taken into account by your algorithm.

The part `if (count == 1)` will happen on the first grade but there will be no calculations because they are all in the `else` part of your code.

What you should do is for example the following (From your code):

```
if (count == 1) {
    largest = mark;
    smallest = mark;
} else {
    if (mark > largest) {
        largest = mark;
    }           
    if (mark < smallest) {
        smallest = mark;
    }
}    // Note that we close the first if-else here

// And so this part will be executed for every input mark
if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 29) {
   rangeOne++;
} else if (mark >= 30 && mark <= 39) {
    rangeTwo++;
} else if (mark >= 40 && mark <= 69) {
    rangeThree++;
} else if (mark >= 70 && mark <= 100) {
    rangeFour++;
}
```